# Ubuntu - how to find live usage of port numbers

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to debug a problem with a apache server, wherein I need to find the application that uses a particular port number. I tried using `netstat`, but didn't help.

The scenario is that I am using `mitmproxy` and `SSL` is also involved, and I find in wireshark a packet where the source and destination IPs are same and are trying to do SSL, but have different port numbers (I can't understand why this packet exists) . I need to find who controlled those port numbers at that instance, so I could possibly find which application is causing this problem.

Can anyone suggest a way ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `lsof -i` which should list the ports being used and their associated processes. You can also check for a specific port with `lsof -i [TCP/UDP]:[Port number]`. As an example, if I wanted to check what was running on port 22, you could run `lsof -i TCP:22` to see.

EDIT: What did netstat return? Because if I run `netstat -anp --tcp --udp | grep LISTEN` it returns the processes listening on various ports.

Comment: netstat won't return a previous history .. I can't find that port number when I run netstat

Comment: Odd, and what about `lsof`? Did that work?